# Angular 6 - Argument type Subscription is not assignable to parameter type Array<any>

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to display data on a table.

**Smart-table-component.ts**

```
export class SmartTableComponent {
clients: Client[];
totalOwed: number;

source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();

constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {
  const data = this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients => this.clients = clients);
  this.source.load(data); // this line returns the error below
}
```

And this is the error:

**Argument type Subscription is not assignable to parameter type Array**

If I go on my ClientService, this is what getClients() does:

```
getClients(): Observable<Client[]> {
this.clients = this.clientsCollection.snapshotChanges()
  .map(changes =>  {
    return changes.map(action => {
      const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Client;
      data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
      return data;
    });
  });
return this.clients;
}
```

So, how can I convert subscription to array?

Comment: You need to call `this.source.load` from inside the subscribe function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning to data directly bind the clients to the source as follows,

```
this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients =>{ 
   this.clients = clients;
   this.source.load(clients);
});
```

Comment: Your answer works, only missing the curly braces after `clients =>`

Comment: thank you @Rosenberg , its fair if the downvoter has a reason as a comment